# Header guard deactivates IntelliSense within it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Well, let's say I have simple code like that:

```
#ifndef SYSTEM_CLASS_H
#define SYSTEM_CLASS_H

class SystemClass {
public:
    SystemClass();
    bool Initialize();
}
#endif
```

My issue is that everything within the header guard is ommited by IntelliSense. Is it intentional? Is there any way to disable it? I tried to look for solution on SO and Google, but I found nothing. I'm using VS 2012 Express, which recently got 3rd update.

Comment: try `#pragma once`. And reopen the solution sometimes make it right.

Comment: What happens if you use `#define SYSTEM_CLASS_H 1` instead?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, both suggestions are great and yes, when I assign 1 to my constant it works. I'm a bit surprised, because I didn't have to do it so far. 
Oddly enough I haven't heard about #pragma once directive, though I'd like to keep header guards in my code for now, as I don't really trust #pragma once directive to be safe-for-each-case feature.